# Writing Python Test Cases to check links in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, http, testing

This is a function that my teammate is using to check the links in an HTML page to see if it is broken or not. The function searches through each link and stores them in the array[] g. My job is to create test cases for this function but I'm not fully sure how to start. I'm a beginner in Python and want to learn how to create more effective test cases.

```
import urllib.request
import re
import urllib.error
def check(url):
    try:
        f= urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError :
            return False
    return True
def trouveurdurls(url):
    f= urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    b=(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
    d = re.findall('<a href=".*?"', b)
    liste=[]
    f.close()
    for el in d:
        g=re.findall('"https?://.*\.*"',el)
        liste.append(g)
    a=[]
    for el in liste:
        chaine= ''.join(map(str,el))
        url=chaine.replace('\'','')
        print(url)
        #check(url)
b=trouveurdurls("http://127.0.0.1/")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based on pytest and VScode as its what I am familiar with. Also good to use a linter. I use flake8.

I assume you have nothing to work with other the raw file. In practice there should be a *lot* more. However to create some tests starting from nothing ...

- Create a folder, place the code you want to test inside
- Open the folder in VSCode (this matters to VSCode)
- Create a test directory, `test`
- `Ctrl+Shift+P` then `Python: Configure Tests`, pick `pytest`, pick `test` as where your tests are
- If all the modules needed are installed VSCode will note there are no tests installed. You will probably have to install some modules, although sometimes VScode helps here.

A `.vscode\settings.json` will hopefully have appeared. Mine looks like:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "test"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true
}
```

Now create `test\__init__.py` (empty) and `test\test_url.py`

```
# I called your file trou.py
from trou import check  # __init__.py needed for the import to work

def test_check():  # pytest finds functions starting with test_
    """A very simple test."""
    assert check("http://stackoverflow.com/") is True
```

The extension `Python Test Explorer for Visual Studio Code` is very useful. To start with test discovery will fail because the file you are testing has errors. The bare minimum I needed to do to make it see the tests was:

```
# b=trouveurdurls("http://127.0.0.1/")
```

The output from pytest should looks something like this. Although VSCode test explorer provides a nice green tick.

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.1.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: c:\xxx\temp
plugins: anyio-2.2.0, asyncio-0.14.0
collected 1 item

test\test_url.py .                                                       [100%]

- generated xml file: C:\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-24832WX0Q0P6CNZbs.xml -
============================== 1 passed in 1.23s ==============================
```